# Weblogic logs parser in python

Tags: python, logging, weblogic

Does anyone know python library to parse Weblogic logs?

It would be great if the library would do a mapping from logs to the python dictionary.

I would like to search for the information as userid or IP address inside the logs, so having the parser would be great to use.

Answer (score 0):

WebLogic access logging uses the "[Extended Log Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Log_Format)" and can also be set to the "Common Log Format". If you search for those formats you'll find plenty of python libraries capable of parsing your WebLogic logs for you.